# Getting every NSDate for this month as NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my app i need to store a URL for every day of the month. From today and backwards. How would i do that?

So far no problem getting todays NSDate as a NSString:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* format = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyyMdd"];

NSString* str = [format stringFromDate:date];
```

So how would i go about, for example, if i wanted the date in a string for, lets say, 17 days ago?

PS. i want to use these dates and store them in a string to fetch urls for every day for the past month, for example www.myurl.com/pictureYEAR-MONTH-DAY.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to Alex's answer, but it looks like his only gets days from the start of the month to whatever day it is today.  Here's how you can get all of the days this month:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSMutableArray *datesThisMonth = [NSMutableArray array];
NSRange rangeOfDaysThisMonth = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:today];

NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSEraCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

for (NSInteger i = rangeOfDaysThisMonth.location; i < NSMaxRange(rangeOfDaysThisMonth); ++i) {
  [components setDay:i];
  NSDate *dayInMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
  [datesThisMonth addObject:dayInMonth];
}
```

This will leave with with an `NSArray` of `NSDates`, with one date per day in the current month.

---

If you want a date that's "17 days ago", you can do that pretty easily too:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *diff = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[diff setDay:-17];

NSDate *seventeenDaysAgo = [cal dateByAddingComponents:diff toDate:today];
```

---

Once you have an `NSDate`, it's pretty simple to turn it into a string:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *date = ...;
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: What if i wanted to create it more dynamically?(not 17 days ago). For example if i wanted to create arrays for each month, containing strings for each day in each of the Month's arrays?

Comment: @user1096112 you could use that `rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:` to find out how many `NSMonthCalendarUnits` are in the `NSYearCalendarUnit` for the current date and (more or less) add another `for` loop around the `for` loop in my answer.  There'd be a bit more to it than that, but that's the general idea.

Comment: This works great. Can you tell me how can i get all the dates in the current year?

Answer (score 6):

Just get the `NSDateComponents` of the current date, then extract the day from that, and write a for loop subtracting from it till you get to 1, each time creating a new date from the components with the day changed, and storing it as a string.

Code can probably say more than words so here you go (tested):

```
NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // you can set this to whatever you like
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; // get todays date
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // needed to work with components
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:(NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
NSUInteger day = [components day];
for (NSUInteger i=day; i>0; i--) {
    // loop through all days till down to 1
    [components setDay:i]; // update the day in the components
    NSDate *date = [cal dateFromComponents:components]; 
    [dates addObject:[fmt stringFromDate:date]]; // add the new date
}

for (NSString *date in dates) {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.myurl.com/picture/%@",date];
    NSLog(@"%@",str); // voila, your URL.
}

[fmt release];
[dates release];
```