# How to get dates of current month in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am developing a app which uses the date, month, year. I want the current month dates,because current month can have 28,29,30,31 days. I have tried to get current year months. but i don't know the code for above. here is my code.

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate           *today           = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar       *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *yearComponents  = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  fromDate:today];
int currentYear  = [yearComponents year];
for(int months = 0; months < 12; months++)
{
    NSString *monthName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols]objectAtIndex: months],currentYear];
    NSLog(@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols]objectAtIndex: months],currentYear);
    [monthArray addObject:monthName];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get day you can you NSDateComponents

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
```

You can add more component units as you need like :`NSMonthCalendarUnit,NSWeekdayCalendarUnit,NSYearCalendarUnit`

Answer (score 7):

`NSCalendar` and its `rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate` method can be use. 
For eg., to get the number of days in the current month:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange range = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSUInteger numberOfDaysInMonth = range.length;
```

Comment: How cant i get each date?? from 01-10-2013 to 31-10-2013

Comment: Is there a way to get individual date?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501502/getting-every-nsdate-for-this-month-as-nsstring