# Get Records between two dates Sqlite

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am saving records with StartDate and EndDate values within sqlite database. Now if i want to fetch records on the basis of today, tomorrow, current week, last week , current month, last month.
should i do this in Sqlite or IOS?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I did not try thats why i am asking if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: if you can save the data in data base it is  possible on retrieve also.

Comment: The problem is to sort the records accordingly.
For e.g if i want to sort records according to current month.

So i have to check if current month dates exists between startdate and enddate.

Comment: after retrieving the data use NSSortDescriptor and use the key it automatically arrange the data in ascending or descending

Comment: Ok this will sort the data and if i want to display only current month's date then?

I mean if startdate and enddate includes current month's dates

Comment: bro this is also based on your condition check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675848/how-to-get-dates-of-current-month-in-objective-c) and compare the array contains particular items add the value else part leave the value